# How to convert current time to EST to ISO 8601 string format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to convert the current time to EST and display it in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ form.
This is what I'm running but it's not giving the time in EST.

```
const now = new Date()
const currentTime = moment(now).tz('America/New_York').toISOString()
```

I'd prefer to this without moment, but an answer using moment would also be helpful.

Comment: moment(now).tz('America/New_York').format() - this helps?